# Only one user can connect to websocket server with tornado at a time

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am trying to develop a websocket server with Python and tornado. This websocket server streams a large database result to the client for some visualization.

The problem that I am facing is that no client can connect until the long process (`send_data`) is finished. It is as if only one client can connect at a time.

Is websocket already an async process or should I implement an async process?

The following is my code:

```
import time
import random
import json
import datetime
import os
import sys
import cx_Oracle
import string
import re
import subprocess
import asyncio
from tornado import websocket, web, ioloop, escape
from datetime import timedelta
from random import randint
from pprint import pprint
from tornado.web import RequestHandler



os.environ['ORACLE_HOME'] = 'pathToOracleHome'
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = "$ORACLE_HOME/lib"
def is_hex(a):
    printable = set(string.printable) - set("\x0b\x0c")
    return any(c not in printable for c in a)
def json_print(d):
    print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))
def printf (format,*args):
    sys.stdout.write (format % args)
def db(database_name='localhost/database'):
    return cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'pwd', database_name)
def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = db().cursor()
    cur.arraysize = 1500
    cur.execute(query, args)
    return cur

class SummaryWebSocketHandler(websocket.WebSocketHandler):
  clients = []  

  def check_origin(self, origin):
      return True

  def on_message(self, message): 
      print ('message received')

  def closeDbConn(self,cur):
      cur.connection.close()

  def query(self, sql):
      cursor = query_db(sql)
      self.send_data(cursor)

  ### THIS IS THE LONG PROCESS ###
  def send_data(self, cur):
      results = {}
      columns = [column[0] for column in cur.description]
      total = 0
      while True:
          Res = []
          rows = cur.fetchmany()
          if rows == []:
              print('no more rows')
              break;
          for row in rows:
              results = {}
              for i, value in enumerate(row):
                  if value == None:
                      value = '-'
                  results[cur.description[i][0]] = value
              Res.append(results)
          self.write_message(json.dumps(Res))
          total =  total + len(rows)
          print('total rows send', total)
      self.write_message("finished sending all data")
      self.on_close(cur)

  def open(self, table):
      print ('Connection established. \n')
      print ('Query string '+table+'\n')
      p = re.compile(r'fields=')
      m  = p.match(table)
      matches = table.split("&")
      print (matches) 

      param_string = ''
      params = []
      if matches:
      for m in matches:
            print('m', m);
            param = ''
            items = m.split('=')
            if items[1] != '':
                param = '--'+items[0]+' '+items[1]
                params.append(param)
      param_string =  " ".join(params) 

      script = "php getStmt.php "+param_string

      print (script)
      proc = subprocess.Popen(script, shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
      sql = proc.stdout.read()
      print (sql)
      self.query(sql)

  def on_close(self, cursor):
      print ('Connection closed.')
      cursor.close()

settings = {'auto_reload': True, 'debug': True}
if __name__ == "__main__":
   print ("Starting websocket server program. Awaiting client requests to open websocket ...")
   application = web.Application([(r"/\/table\/(.*)",SummaryWebSocketHandler), 
                            ]
                            ,**settings)
   application.listen(3001)
   ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: New clients can't  connect because `send_data` is blocking the event loop. Try running `send_data` in a separate thread using `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @xyres that might just postpone the problem, instead, OP should seek async DB library. Assuming MySQL, `TorMySQL` is a good option.

Comment: @desertkun unfortunately the database is in oracle, so I am using cx_Oracle. Is this an async DB library?

Comment: Then, well, you can try at least configure db to be [non-blocking](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/vasiliev-python-concurrency-087536.html) and then you can wrap these calls in gen.Task. Also, you're missing the whole power of Tornado: [@coroutine](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html)

Comment: @desertkun, I am very new to tornado and whole websocket business. Would you mind showing me how to using coroutine with my code? Greatly appreciated!